# Stop if statement without breaking for loop and affect other ifs

Tags: python, loops, csv, if-statement, for-loop

I am processing some .csv files using python. In the .csv file, there are a lot of rows. There are multiple rows that are the same. 
After opening this file, in the `for row in reader:` loop, I want to find the first repeated row and assign it to a variable. Then keep on processing other rows in the loop.

The issue is that without breaking the loop when it meets another same row, the if statement will run again. I just want the if statement run once when the first wanted row is found. It will cause redundancy to run the if-statement multiple times while once is enough.

How to only run this if statement only the first time the if condition is fulfilled? I can break the loop when the first wanted row is found and then repeat `for row in reader:` to process other rows, but I think there must be a way to do this in a single loop.

Comment: Keep track of whether it's the first time or not.

Comment: Please don't degrade this question. I did do a lot search online for this question. But most questions popped out are about how to break the loop. This question will provide future reference for similar questions from newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a common pattern in in programming. Set a flag once you've fulfilled the condition for the first time. then ignore that condition if your flag is already set.

```
already_set = False
row_variable = None
for row in reader:
    if (row meets some condition) and (not already_set):
        row_variable = row
        already_Set = True
# now row_variable holds the first row that met your condition
# or it holds None if no rows meet the condition
```

Comment: with this format, you can even reduce variables by just doing `not row_variable` since `None` asserts to `False`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a boolean value to represent whether you've already processed a matching row or not, and an additional check in your `if` statement.

```
found = False
for r in rows:
    if ( r == "whatever conidition for the row" and not found):
        found = True
        # processing code
```